# Weird binary to decimal conversion in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, binary, type-conversion, decimal

I try to convert binaries to decimals in MySQL, but there is a big problem :

```
SELECT CONV(BINARY('10000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111100000000000000000'),2,10)
```

and

```
SELECT CONV(BINARY('11111111111111111111111111111111111111101111111111011110111100000'),2,10)
```

give the same wrong result : 18446744073709551615

Although, if I use the bindec() PHP function, I obtain respectively :

3.6893488147386E+19 and 1.8446744073743E+19. These results are expected and I would to obtain them in my SQL request output.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: you have 65 characters in your number. That's one too many for MySQL.

Comment: Thanks, that's the problem indeed, but I don't find a substitute solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say for simplicity's sake that all the strings to convert are 65 characters long. That means that bit shifting right one place would make the string convertable.  So something like this might work:

```
SELECT CONV(LEFT(mystring,64))*2 + RIGHT(mystring,1);
```